# Getfiles() UnAuthorizedAccessAcception in WIN7

Tags: c#, exception, windows-7, unauthorized

**Problems**

1. UnAuthorizedAccessException: When searching a directory recursively such as C:\
     A "Access to the path 'c:\Documents and Settings\' is denied." Occurs even with UAC  Priveledges upgraded & Administrator group access.

**Attempted Methods**

1. Try & Catch: Using either one of these methods(Exception, UnAuthorizedAccessException, Blank Catch, continue)

**Questions**

1. How do you handle this kind of exception and continue running your program as normal? This needs to work both on non-admin and administrator accounts.

**Example Code**

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace filecheck
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 0;
            int html = 0;
            try
            {
                string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "*.html", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                foreach (string files in filePaths)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(files.IndexOf("html")))
                    {
                        html++;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(files);
                    i++;

                }
                Console.Write("# Files found: {0} Html: {1)", i, html);
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know it's not allowed to programmaticly access the documents and settings. Not even as superadmin

Comment: @Theun: What is a "superadmin"?

Comment: @Theun: I assume you are talking about the Hidden Administrator(Built-in) account. I have not tried that but that should give you unrestricted access to the system. I don't need that. Just searching for a way to get around my search's being blocked by this annoying unauthroizedaccess non-sense.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the only way to handle this is by doing the recursion manually. Even in Microsoft's own [sample code](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303974) they do it this way, just to avoid that the whole search fails because one or more directories can not be accessed.

So in other words, only use `SearchOption.AllDirectories` when you're searching a limited subset of directories which you're certain won't contain any directories which you won't have access to.

Comment: Even there approach does not working in the "C:\" it doesn't return anything at all. If I change the sample directory search to something like c:\user\<user>\Desktop it finds everything I ask it too.
 
How do I know which directorys to skip? Do I have to check for folder security attributes and skip them if the current user role does not have the rights? There has to be a possible solution to this. They say you can handle the exceptions and move on but this one just totally stops your program from running it has me baffled.

Comment: @Nightforce2: In Windows 7 (and probably Vista too) the root of the system drive (so usually C:\\) is write protected by default, but since your code only reads I would have thought that it wouldn't fail because of that so I'm not sure why you're having that problem. If your account didn't have read permissions to the root of the system drive I'd thought that it wouldn't be able to actually run Windows...

Comment: I assume it is because of UAC. It causes more problems then solutions.

Answer (score 0):

To get your program working with both admin and non-admin users you either need to impersonate the user or re-build your application to "Run as Administrator" every time it is being executed or used by any user. To build this kind of application you need to add app.manifest file to your project and un-comment the following line of setting in app.manifest

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

For more read here: http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/How-To-Build-UAC-Compatible-Application-In-NET.aspx

Comment: This is not applicable as I am in the Administrator role and using UAC for upgraded priveledges. So you see setting this option only makes UAC give me a prompt for user escalation confirmation when I start my program.