# System.UnauthorizedAccessException C# in winforms

Tags: c#, linq, permissions

The issue is System.UnauthorizedAccessException on *recycle bin* or *documents and settings* folders/files. (VS2010 .NET 4.0 C#)

The following LINQ code to query directory sizes.  I have tried GetFiles and EnumerateFiles.  I am definitely running as admin.  In the commented code you can see I tried testing for some attributes from another Stack post without success.

```
DirectorySize(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\\"),true);

public static long DirectorySize(DirectoryInfo dInfo, bool includeSubDir)
{
    // Enumerate all the files
    long totalSize = dInfo.EnumerateFiles().Sum(file => file.Length);
        //.Where(d => (d.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReparsePoint) == 0 && (d.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) == 0)
        //.Sum(file => file.Length);

    if (includeSubDir) // Subdirs?
    {
        // Enumerate all sub-directories
        totalSize += dInfo.EnumerateDirectories().Sum(dir => DirectorySize(dir, true));
            //.Where(d => (d.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReparsePoint) == 0 && (d.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) == 0)
            //.Sum(dir => DirectorySize(dir, true));
    }
    return totalSize;
}
```

I would like to get a concise LINQ method where I don't have to manually loop and test every folder/dir.  I found some MS code for duplicates that operates similarly. It errors out the same too.

My thanks in advance,

Comment: I think you need to swallow the pill and try/catch the exception. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5957525/284240

Comment: This has nothing to do with Winforms

Comment: The reason for mentioning winforms was to establish the environment and eliminate the usual asp.net/IIS environment from the discussion.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think you are right and the try/catch cannot be incorporated inline. I _knew_ that code was too pretty and concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`try/catch` to the rescue as demonstrated in the [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx). There are also [alternatives](http://rwtools.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There are other references to this in Stack Overflow; but you probably need to define permissions for your application itself.
[Setting Perms](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/206cfa9d-3e5b-43be-840f-49a221e10749)

There is also this little nugget [ C:\Users is a JUNCTION];
[C#: Access to path <'filepath'> is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228426/c-access-to-path-filepath-is-denied)